# Passing an iterable, or a collection to a function

Tags: rust

Consider this pseudo-pseudocode. I have quite some difficulties with the `keyarg` argument below,

```rust
type MapSet<K,V> = HashMap<K,HashSet<V>>;

fn contract<K,V,V1>(left: &MapSet<K,V>, right: &MapSet<V,V1>, 
                    out: &mut MapSet<K,V1>,
                    keyarg: Option(__something_iterable__) {

    let keys = match keyarg {
        Some(keys) => {
            keys
        },
        None => {
           left.keys()
        },
    }

    for &k in keys {
        // ... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

The function is used sometimes like this,

```rust
let x: MapSet<u32,String>;
let y: MapSet<String,u32>;
let out: MapSet<u32,u32>;
let kk: HashSet<u32>;

// ... snip ...

contract(x,y,out,kk);
```

And, at other times like that,

```
let x: MapSet<u32,String>;
let y: MapSet<String,u32>;
let out: MapSet<u32,u32>;
contract(x,y,out,None);
```

In other words, I am sometimes using `keyarg` argument to pass an `Option` with a reference to a `HashSet` containing the keys I want to iterate over and at other times I want to iterate over all the keys contained in `left` argument, so the `keyarg` becomes simply `None`.

But, so far I have always ended up in a problem with the `match` which complains that None leads to `Keys` object and Some branch to HashSet (type mismatch error).

My question is how to define the `keyarg` argument so that the branches of `match` are compatible with each other. That is, I want to express the fact that the variable `keys` is just something one can iterate over to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `keyarg` will always match your `MapSet` iterator, and in your pseudo code it doesn't, you'll need `keys` to be a trait object. The iterator for `MapSet<K,V>` has the trait `Iterator<Item = &K>`, so you can match it into a `Box` like so:

```
let keys: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &K>> = match keyarg {
    Some(keys) => Box::new(...),
    None => Box::new(left.keys()),
}
```

---

As far as determining what `keyarg` should be, the generic way would be to accept any matching iterable like so:

```
fn contract<'a, K, V, V1, I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a K>>(
                       // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    left: &'a MapSet<K, V>,
    right: &MapSet<V, V1>,
    out: &mut MapSet<K, V1>,
    keyarg: Option<I>,
) {    
    let keys: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &K>> = match keyarg {
        Some(keys) => Box::new(keys.into_iter()),
        None => Box::new(left.keys()),
    };

    // ...
}
```

And this is very ergonomic for passing a `HashSet` but causes a problem for the `None` case:

```
// This works
contract(&x, &y, &mut out, Some(&kk));

// This fails with error: "type annotations needed, cannot infer type for type parameter `I`"
contract(&x, &y, &mut out, None);
```

So you'd have to annotate `None` with some dummy iterator type (like `Box<...>` or `std::iter::Empty` or something) which isn't ideal.

Instead you can make `keyarg` the boxed iterator directly:

```
fn contract_1<'a, K, V, V1>(
    left: &'a MapSet<K, V>,
    right: &MapSet<V, V1>,
    out: &mut MapSet<K, V1>,
    keyarg: Option<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a K> + 'a>>,
                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
) {
    let keys: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &K>> = match keyarg {
        Some(keys) => keys,
        None => Box::new(left.keys()),
    };

    // ...
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
contract(&x, &y, &mut out, Some(Box::new(kk.iter())));
contract(&x, &y, &mut out, None);
```

Comment: Thanks for the most beautifully formatted answer to any question I posted on SO so far!

Comment: Do you know, will the compiler allocate keys that get the value from match as a new object, or will it be smart enough to reuse left.keys(), or whatever is inside Some(keys)?

Comment: Not *exactly* sure what you're asking, `Box` represents an allocation but `left.keys()` will just be *moved* into the box. There is no additional allocation with the latter method since the value in `Some(keys)` is already a `Box`.